# How to display xml information using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xml

I am confused on how to read information from an .xml file using AJAX. All I want my program to do is display a button that the user can press, then it will display a list of movies in the .xml file. Right now my webpage shows the button but when a user presses it nothing happens. I'm going to post my 3 files and hopefully someone can help me out.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AJAX - responseXML</title>
    <script src="ajax.js"></script>
    <script>
    function getMovies() {
            var xmlHttp = xmlHttpObjCreate();
            if (!xmlHttp) {
                    alert("The browser doesn't support this action.");
                    return;
            }

            xmlHttp.onload = function() {
                    if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                            // Get XML Document
                            var xmlDoc = xmlHttp.responseXML;

                            // Variable for our output
                            var output = '';

                            // Build output by parsing XML
                            movieTitles = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('title');

                            for (i = 0; i < movieTitles.length; i++) {
                                    output += movieTitles[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
                            }

                            // Get div object
                            var divObj = document.getElementById('movieBox');

                            // Set the div's innerHTML
                            divObj.innerHTML = output;
                    }
            }

            xmlHttp.open("GET", "movies.xml", true);
            xmlHttp.send();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>My Movies</h3>
    <div id="movieBox"></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="getMovies()">Get Movie Titles</button>
</body>
</html>
```

ajax.js

```
function xmlHttpObjCreate() {
var xmlHttp; 
try
 {xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
catch (e)
{try
  {
 xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
 }
catch (e)
  {
 try
   {
   xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 catch (e)
   {
   return false;
   }
 }
}
 return xmlHttp;
}
```

movies.xml

```
 <?xml version= "1.0"?>
 <collection>
    <movies>
            <title> Gone with the Wind
                        <year> 1939 </year>
                                  </title>

            <title> 2001: A Space Odyssey
                            <year> 1968 </year>
                                            </title>

            <title> Jurassic Park
                            <year> 1993 </year>
                                            </title>

            <title> The Shawshank Redmption
                            <year> 1994 </year>
                                            </title>

            <title> Balto
                            <year> 1995 </year>
                                            </title>

    </movies>
</collection>
```

This is the error that I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
```

Comment: That doesn't look much like an XML file, but whatever. Have you checked the browser developer console for errors?

Comment: @pointy How do I do that?

Comment: Hit the F12 key to bring up the developer console.

Comment: There should be a menu option to open the Safari console.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null Is the error I get

Comment: Well that means that `responseXML` is `null`.

Comment: @Pointy do you know what I should change to fix it? Im stuck

Comment: Well that could be caused by several different things. For example, if the XML is not valid, `responseXML` will be `null`. Also that happens if the server does not set the MIME type to `text/xml`. There could be other server errors that cause it.

Comment: @Pointy So in this case it is probably because the XML file is not valid?

Comment: Well if the XML file actually looks exactly like what you posted in the question, then yes; that's not XML at all.

Comment: lol How do I make an xml file?

Comment: [Here's a (very) basic tutorial.](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningxml/a/how-to-write-your-first-xml-document.htm) There is a vast amount of material on the Internet about using XML.

Comment: @Pointy I updated my .xml file and I still get this error??

Comment: Try calling `xmlHttp.overrideMimeType("text/xml")` before you call `.send()`. Keep an eye on the developer console for other possible errors too.

Comment: Kind of a simple debugging thought: Have you tried visiting the XML file's URL directly in your browser, to see what your XMLHttpRequest is seeing? For all we know, the server might be giving a blank file for some reason. Also: Does your browser URL start with "http://localhost", or "file:///home/Users/..."

Comment: What does this function do?
xmlHttp.overrideMimeType("text/xml")

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error when reading in an XML file using AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26787902/error-when-reading-in-an-xml-file-using-ajax)

Comment: @jimmy don't repost your question!!!