# Error when reading in an XML file using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xml, json

I get an error in my .html file when I am trying to display an xml file using AJAX. My program is supposed to have a button that can read in a json file and another button that can read in an xml file. The json button works just fine, but the xml button gives me an error when I press it and I can't figure it out.

The error that I am getting in

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null   index.html:34
```

Here is my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AJAX - responseJSON</title>
    <script src="ajax.js"></script>
    <script>

    function getMovies() {
            var xmlHttp = xmlHttpObjCreate();
            if (!xmlHttp) {
                    alert("The browser doesn't support this action.");
                    return;
            }

            xmlHttp.onload = function() {
                    if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                            // Get XML Document
                            var xmlDoc = xmlHttp.responseXML;

                            // Variable for our output
                            var output = '';

                            // Build output by parsing XML
                            movieTitles = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('title');

                            for (i = 0; i < movieTitles.length; i++) {
                                    output += movieTitles[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
                            }

                            // Get div object
                            var divObj = document.getElementById('movieBox');

                            // Set the div's innerHTML
                            divObj.innerHTML = output;
                    }
            }

            xmlHttp.open("GET", "movies.xml", true);
            xmlHttp.overrideMimeType("text/xml")
            xmlHttp.send();
    }


    function getContent() {
            var xmlHttp = xmlHttpObjCreate();
            if (!xmlHttp) {
                    alert("The browser doesn't support this action.");
                    return;
            }

            xmlHttp.onload = function() {
                    if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {

                            // Get Response Text
                            var response = xmlHttp.responseText;

                            // Prints the JSON string
                            console.dir(response);

                            // Get div object
                            var divObj = document.getElementById('contentBox');

                            // We used JSON.parse to turn the JSON string into an object
                            var responseObject = JSON.parse(response);

                            // This is our object
                            console.dir(responseObject);


                            // We can use that object like so:
                            divObj.innerHTML = "Hi I am " + responseObject.name + " and my pet is " + responseObject.pet;

                    }
            }

            xmlHttp.open("GET", "json.php", true);
            xmlHttp.send();
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>My Content</h3>
    <div id="contentBox"></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="getContent();">Get Content</button>

    <h3>My movies</h3>
    <div id"movieBox"></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="getMovies();"> Get Movies</button>
</body>
</html>
```

ajax.js

```
function xmlHttpObjCreate() {
var xmlHttp; 
try
 {xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
catch (e)
{try
  {
 xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
 }
catch (e)
  {
 try
   {
   xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 catch (e)
   {
   return false;
   }
 }
}
 return xmlHttp;
}
```

movies.xml

```
 <?xml version= "1.0"?>
 <collection>
    <movies>
            <title> Gone with the Wind
                        <year> 1939 </year>
                                  </title>

            <title> 2001: A Space Odyssey
                            <year> 1968 </year>
                                            </title>

            <title> Jurassic Park
                            <year> 1993 </year>
                                            </title>

            <title> The Shawshank Redmption
                            <year> 1994 </year>
                                            </title>

            <title> Balto
                            <year> 1995 </year>
                                            </title>

    </movies>
</collection>
```

Answer (score 1):

Invalid HTML:

```
<div id"movieBox"></div>
       ^---missing =
```

No `=`, no valid `id` attribute, therefore your `getElementById()` fails and returns `null` to signify failure.